# Convert gnu screen status line to tmux status line

Tags: shell, gnu-screen, tmux

I am using the following screen status line, configured in my screenrc:

[image: screen status]

I configured it using the following line:

```
hardstatus alwayslastline
hardstatus string '%{= kG}[ %{G}%H %{g}][%= %{=kw}%?%-Lw%?%{r}(%{W}%n*%f %t%?(%u)%?%{r})%{w}%?%+Lw%?%?%= %{g}][%{B}%Y-%m-%d %{W}%c %{g}]'
```

I did not create this theme, I don't remember where I found it, but I really like it.

I am now converting my configuration to `tmux` and I can't seem to replicate this configuration in my `tmux.conf`.

I got this far:

```
set -g status-bg black
set -g status-fg white
set -g status-left '#[fg=green]#H'
set-window-option -g window-status-current-attr bright
set-window-option -g window-status-current-bg red
```

Which produces this line:

[image: tmux status]]

Please ignore the different hostname, it's on a different server

What configuration can I use in `tmux` to produce a status line similar to the first one?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the exception of the red brackets around the highlighted window, this is the closest approximation that I can easily configure in `tmux 1.5`:

```
# default statusbar colors
set -g status-fg white
set -g status-bg default

# default window title colors
set-window-option -g window-status-fg white
set-window-option -g window-status-bg default
set-window-option -g window-status-attr dim

# active window title colors
set-window-option -g window-status-current-fg white
set-window-option -g window-status-current-bg default
set-window-option -g window-status-current-attr bright

# statusline
set -g status-left '#[fg=green][ #H ]['
set -g status-right '#[fg=green]][ #[fg=blue]%Y-%m-%d #[fg=white]%I:%M #[fg=green]]'
```

[image: tmux statusline]

If you want the highlighted window in red, use:

```
set-window-option -g window-status-current-fg red
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try this too:

```
set-window-option -g window-status-current-format "#[fg=red](#[fg=white]#I#F$ #W#[fg=red])"
set-window-option -g window-status-format "#[fg=normal]#I#F$ #W"
```

Makes your window list look like in your screen configuration.